# Describing the individual differences between different members of my Enslaver Species based on the images provided?

Tags: characters

[image: Enslaver 1]
[image: ENSLAVER W]
[image: Enslaver 3]
[image: enslaver 4]

Basically all enslavers are mind controlling alien abominations that are the size of buildings and sky scrapers. They can each control the weather,  have limited telekinesis , infequent teleportation and extreme telepathy and mind control.

Nevertheless there isn't one enslaver. And though only four appear over the course of the story I want to flesh out their physical differences and similarities. How would I show or describe them individually?

Comment: Do the differences matter to the story? Are there characters that see more than one of these things?

Comment: Yep over the course of the story the characters see and interact with four of them. Some "friendlier" than others. But even friendliest see humans as no more than cattle.

Answer (score 2):

Since your wee beasties are sapient and self-directed and a member of a species, that implies some level of culture. And since they can travel between planets or  across dimensions of reality -- they aren't native to Earth so they had to get here somehow -- this implies a sophisticated knowledge of science, which implies technology.

Human culture gave rise to tattooing as a means of demonstrating group affiliation or individual expression. Human technology gave rise to wrist watches and walkmans.  This suggests ways that you can decide how to describe your creatures.  What group affiliations do they have? Do they practice some equivalent of tattooing or scarring, even if it is just their equivalent of Shriners or  Wu Tan Clown Posse.

What is their technology like?  Does it give rise to synthetic-biology that look like worms wrapped around their legs to us humans -- like they have some sort of parasite -- but in fact before some valuable function like blood pressure regulation or hunger management -- cause who doesn't want to lose a few tons.

Then there would be biological differences.  Do they all have the same skin?  Do some have fur?  Do some have scales?  Scales and fur? That sounds pretty cool, actually.  So I'm taking it back. Is about what kind species variation do they exhibit, based on the environments where they evolved?

Lastly,  sexual differences.  What are this species' primary and secondary and tertiary sex markers? How did pre-enslavids differentiate between potential mates?

Answer (score 0):

How does the "Leviathan Kings" sound?
Also, if they each have different abilities, I would name them based off that.

Normal thing for large entities, they are called leviathans. Based on information provided from google,

What makes a creature a leviathan?
Any fauna species large enough to lack natural predators can be classified as Leviathan; they need not be predatory.

---

(Will edit when i feel like answering more of your question. sorry, i'm currently pre-occupied.)

Answer (score 0):

The humans could come up with names based on physical descriptions ("I saw Orange Bottom talking to Two Lumps yesterday"), or based on differences in the way they communicate with the humans - which could be the equivalent of timbre or tone of voice ("What did Squeaky say to Rumble?"), or the sort of things they communicated (think of the sort of nicknames children give their teachers based on pet phrases or style).

I'm guessing "Enslavers" is what the humans call them - they see humans as no more than cattle, and no farmer ever talked about enslaving the pigs. What do they call their species, or is "Enslavers" a human approximation of a telepathic concept expressing vague dominance? If they refer to each other in telepathic communication with humans, or when humans are around and "listening", and there's a translation of the way they describe each other - even if it seems no more than a jumble of consonants - any humans could use those terms as names (though the creatures would then know who the humans meant, so human nicknames might be better for - shall we say "informal" - communication among the humans).